# CakePHP, extensions and layouts

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a controller method that has long been handling JSON requests by parsing that extension, but now I need to open it up to cross domain ajax so I'd like to offer a JSONP variant by parsing that extension as well. I've already updated my `routes.php` file:

```
Router::parseExtensions( 'json', 'jsonp' );
```

So far all is well, but the happiness ends when the results are rendered. While the `.json` extension automagically picks up the `json/default.ctp` layout, the `.jsonp` content continues to adopt the non-specific default layout (and all of its unnecessary HTML content). I've tried using `RequestHandler::setContent()` to set the response content type to both `json` and `js`, but that doesn't seem to be what triggers the call to a given layout directory.

Does anyone know what does determine which content-specific layout directory is called? I tried creating `jsonp/default.ctp` and I've tried creating a `js/default.ctp` layout with my JSONP result, but nothing seems to engage. I just get the normal default.

Any insight into how extensions/content type are mapped to these layout directories would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've temporarily solved this by explicitly setting the `layoutPath` value:

```
$this->layoutPath = $params['url']['ext'];
```

This feels like one of those things where there must be a better solution, but maybe this is it. I'm going to leave the question open for a bit in the hopes that someone else has a solution that involves Cake's automagic.